# Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Hierarchy Request Error'

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I'm getting error while replacing or adding a child into a node.

Required is :

I want to change this to..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<contacts>
  <person>Adam</person>
  <person>Eva</person>
  <person>John</person>
  <person>Thomas</person>
</contacts>
```

like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<contacts>
  <person>Adam</person>
  <p>
      <person>Eva</person>
  </p>
  <person>John</person>
  <person>Thomas</person>
</contacts>
```

error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Hierarchy Request Error'

my code is

```
function changeTagName($changeble) {
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($changeble); $index++) {
        $new = $xmlDoc->createElement("p");
        $new ->setAttribute("channel", "wp.com");
        $new ->appendChild($changeble[$index]);
        $old = $changeble[$index];
        $result = $old->parentNode->replaceChild($new , $old);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can see xml requirement in question details...

Comment: when I trying to use replaceChild its getting error saying  'Hierarchy Request Error' I am not getting idea what I'm making mistake

Comment: I just want a node is needed to be enclosed in p tag thats it.

Comment: yep sure next time..  thanks for suggestion..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29324/discussion-between-chandan-pasunoori-and-hakre)

Comment: I restored the original XML examples so it's better to understand and lined-up with the answer. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The error *Hierarchy Request Error* with *DOMDocument* in PHP means that you are trying to move a node into itself. Compare this with the snake in the following picture:

[image: Snake eats itself]

Similar this is with your node. You move the node into itself. That means, the moment you want to replace the person with the paragraph, the person is already a children of the paragraph.

The *appendChild()* method effectively already moves the person out of the DOM tree, it is not part any longer:

```
$para = $doc->createElement("p");
$para->setAttribute('attr', 'value');
$para->appendChild($person);

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<contacts>
  <person>Adam</person>

  <person>John</person>
  <person>Thomas</person>
</contacts>
```

Eva is already gone. Its *parentNode* is the paragraph already.

So Instead you first want to replace and then append the child:

```
$para = $doc->createElement("p");
$para->setAttribute('attr', 'value');
$person = $person->parentNode->replaceChild($para, $person);
$para->appendChild($person);

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<contacts>
  <person>Adam</person>
  <p attr="value"><person>Eva</person></p>
  <person>John</person>
  <person>Thomas</person>
</contacts>
```

Now everything is fine.

Comment: this works exactly what I want.. And very very thanks for good explanation.. Thank you